# Solution about NestedIterators

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am Japanese. Please forgive me for my poor English.(Thanks for gxxgle translate.)

How should I solve when my code got pointed out by RubyCritic / Reek's NestedIterators? Please tell me what kind of solution is available.

For example,
1) Lower the nesting level using map etc,
2) Design such that it completes by calling methods of the elements of the collection rather than manipulating the elements of the elements of the collection.

my code got pointed out by RubyCritic/Reek's NestedIterators:

```
def check_in_hotel_bookings_all
  set_booking
  @booking.hotel_bookings.each do |hotel_booking|
    hotel_booking.checked_in_at = Time.now
    hotel_booking.save
    hotel_booking.hotel_bookings_customers.each do |customer|
 NestedIterators BookingsController#check_in_hotel_bookings_all contains iterators nested 2 deep

      customer.checked_in_at = hotel_booking.checked_in_at
      customer.save
    end
  end
  render json: true
end
```

and I am trying to do this:

```
booking.hotel_bookings.map(&:customers).map(&check_in_now)
booking.hotel_bookings.map(&:check_in_now).map(&:save)
```

Comment: Hi Kouzou. Can you provide any examples of what you are trying to do? Your description is not clear enough. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to make simple methods and use less chaining and less iterators. So this.map(&:thing).map(&:other_thing).map(&:third_thing) is difficult to understand and very difficult to write tests.

Move the code to a model

```
@booking.hotel_bookings.each do |booking|
  booking.check_in_all_customers!(Time.now.utc)
end
render json: true
```

model HotelBooking

```
def check_in_all_customers!(time)
  self.checked_in_at = time
  save!
  hotel_bookings_customers.each do |customer|
    customer.checked_in_at = time
    customer.save
  end
end
```

or you can add the method `check_in_all_customers` to the `has_many` association-

```
HotelBooking.has_many :hotel_bookings_customers do
  def check_in_all(time)
    proxy_association.target.each do |customer| 
      customer.checked_in = time
      customer.save
    end
  end
end
```

controller

```
@booking.hotel_bookings_customers.check_in_all(Time.now)
```

it's the same number of iterations and nesting when you unroll it all, but it's easier to understand and easier to write tests.

Comment: or you can add method check_in_all_customers to the association-